# Unknown error shows up in my pygame script with the ""for event in event.get()""

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying right know to begin with the pygame library and I follow a tutorial (you can find it right here:
https://dr0id.bitbucket.io/legacy/pygame_tutorial01.html )

My objective is to display an image on the screen and the transform it (e.g. move it, set alpha, background...)
So far, I've tried to search similar errors as mine, but found no precise examples in internet.
My code looks like this :

```
from pygame import *

def main():

#initialize
init()
#logo and caption
logo = image.load("logo32x32.png")
display.set_icon(logo)
display.set_caption("minimal game")
#create and size the screen
screen = display.set_mode((1366,700))
#set running var for the main loop
running = True

#Display an image, refresh the screen
blit = image.load("logo32x32.png")
screen.blit(blit, (32,32))
display.flip()

#main loop
while running:
    #exit the loop if event is QUIT
    for event in event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

#run main only if the module execute as a main script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The result I get by executing this script is a window with the image I wanted in the top left-hand corner for like 2 secs and then the application close by itself.

When I come back in VS code, it shows the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Sacha PERUCHON\Documents\Cours\SNT\Cycle2\Python Scripts> & "C:/Users/Sacha 

PERUCHON/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe" "c:/Users/Sacha PERUCHON/Documents/Cours/SNT/Cycle2/Python Scripts/pygame_minimal.py"
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.10)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Sacha PERUCHON\Documents\Cours\SNT\Cycle2\Python Scripts\pygame_minimal.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\Sacha PERUCHON\Documents\Cours\SNT\Cycle2\Python Scripts\pygame_minimal.py", line 24, in main
    for event in event.get():
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'event' referenced before assignment
```

Any help is would be appreciated.

Comment: You're naming your variable (`event`) the same as the built-in pygame variable `event`. Either rename your variable to something else or use `import pygame` and `pygame.event` instead of your current import.

Comment: This is why importing everything with `from pygame import *` should always be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try for event in pygame.event.get()

Also, just do import pygame, not from pygame import *

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).